# How to resize a div without disturbing other divs in css

Tags: css, position, z-index, css-transitions

I am working on an application where I have a lot of tiles in my page which are basically divs. I want to modify the hover property of the div to enlarge it. My current css is something like this:

```
 .livetile{
   height: 110px;
   margin: 5px;
   padding: 0px;
   width: 110px;
   position: absolute;
   transition:width 2s;
   -webkit-transition:width 2s;
  }

 .live-tile:hover{
   -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
   -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
   -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 1px #fff;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 1px #fff;
   box-shadow: 0 0 3px 1px #333;
 }
```

The scaling effect seems to be working fine. However if instead of scaling I try to explicitly resize the div like so:

```
 .live-tile:hover{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
  }
```

Then the tiles surrounding the hovered div get repositioned to accomodate it. I however want it to come to the front to produce some sort of a pop-out effect without the other divs getting repositioned.

In other words I don't want to just scale the display, I just want to change the dimensions of the div so that even if it overlaps with other divs, it just comes to the front without displacing any other divs.

I also tried setting the `z-index` of the hovered div to a higher integer value, but still it doesn't seem to be doing the trick. I have just started experimenting with CSS transitions and animations. Any help is deeply appreciated.

**Edit**
I have tried to make a simple [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JVqEz/2/) to illustrate the problem I am having. I don't want the other divs to get resized. I hope I could explain myself clearly.

*Note* - I want CSS solutions only. I know this can be achieved using Jquery.

Comment: Can you set up a jsfiddle? You shouldn't be having this issue, when an element is absolutely positioned, it is taken out of document flow and will not affect the layout of other elements.

Comment: Scaling is different than explicit resizing. If scaling is working, why not stick with scaling?

Answer (score 2):

Try using z-index on die hover-effect. This should work if you want to overlap the other items...(posistion has to be set!)

Answer (score 0):

you can increase the width (or) max-width property of #holder

```
#holder{
max-width: 650px;
height: 160px;
display: block;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
z-index: 20;
}
```

check here : http://jsfiddle.net/vbYbY/

Comment: I do not want any of the other divs to get resized. I just want the div I hover on to get enalarged and overlap over the other divs and sort of pop out. I don't want to increase the width of the `holder` to accomodate the increase in size of the divs